# Difference between 絶叫｛ぜっきょう｝する and 怒鳴｛どな｝る (to shout)

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

I've learnt 2 verbs, 絶叫｛ぜっきょう｝する (to shout, to scream, to exclaim) and 怒鳴｛どな｝る (to shout; to yell)

They seems to have the same meaning, can someone explain the context in which to use one and the other?

If you know other variants (for example 叫｛さけ｝ぶ、唱｛とな｝える、声｛こえ｝を建｛た｝てる、大声｛おおごえ｝を出｛だ｝す、がなり立｛た｝てる、どやす), please feel free to compare them as well, thank you

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is your question-asking m to search a dictionary for every word that includes that definition and just ask how they differ? Or are these words you're learning in a class or some more-structured way?

Comment: I'm learning on my own following [KanjiDamage](http://www.kanjidamage.com/kanji), and studying on Memrise ([kanji](http://www.memrise.com/course/351255/kanji-onyomi-kunyomi/), [jukugo](http://www.memrise.com/course/351257/kanji-jukugo/)). Since the definitions are so close for 絶叫する and 怒鳴る, I always confuse them, so I'd like to know something that differentiate them so I can improve the question.

Explanation with variants is not required for me to approve an answer, but other people went out of their way to do that on other questions, and I really appreciated it, hence now suggesting it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

絶叫する can be used with anything; you are scared, sad, surprised, angry (possibly less common with angry), whereas 怒鳴る always means you are angry.

Comment: Is that really all there is to it?

When I searched by myself, I thought 怒鳴る might be for animal shouts (bellow, roar), and 絶叫 only for human. That was only an assumption, I guess I was wrong. Accepting your answer.

Comment: @Fandekasp - look at the first character in 怒鳴る. There's a hint that it would be used for anger.

Comment: That's basically it.  Remember the movie Scary Movie?  The J-title is 最終絶叫計画.  Kind of furthers the argument in the accepted answer. Also, the former would never be used in an argument. The latter?  My future ex-wife has told me "怒鳴らないで" maybe 2,000 times over they years but never the other. :)

Comment: @Fandekasp - Animals never 怒鳴る, they only do [吠]{ほ}える. 怒鳴る is only for human too.